# Angular2 Can't change css style dynamically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm using angular2 to style a few input forms, they become disabled when the user doesn't have permission to modify them, but When an admin logs, the inputs are enabled.
To make it more  obvious this i tried to style them, gray when disabled, white when enabled.

in the html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [style.background]="cssColor" name="" [disabled]="!editionEnable" placeholder="value"
                                    [(ngModel)]="class.property" />
```

i tried with `[style.backgroundColor]="cssColor"` too and didn't change the background color.
Also tried  `[ngStyle]="{'background-color': cssColor}">` and in the code tried to declare cssColor like this:

- cssColor:string="#F0F0F0 !important";
- cssColor:string="#F0F0F0";
- cssColor:string="F0F0F0";

i added the !important because editing with the web developer tools in firefox, the background color doesn't change if the !important is not there.

**note:** i'm using twitter bootstrap

Any ideas on what i'm dooing wrong? with angularjs was far more simple to do this.

Comment: I assume cssColor is set in your component class.  Give it a default value.  Then toggle it based on editionEnable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [style.background]="setCssColor()" name="" [disabled]="!editionEnable" placeholder="value"
                                    [(ngModel)]="class.property" />
```

and in your component, something like this:

```
setCssColor() {
    if(this.editionEnable) {
      return "#F0F0F0 !important";
    } else {
      return "#00ff"; //whatever color
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, it didn't help, also i added to the css file but nothing changed

Comment: Here is a working plunk which does what you are after - not sure why it didnt work for you https://plnkr.co/edit/uBNF65?p=preview

Comment: i'm using bootstrap, not sure if bootstrap has priority over my css

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Inside the component:

```
public cssColor:string="#F0F0F0";
```

Inside the component.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color':  cssColor}"  placeholder="value" />
```

Also It could be worth mentioning, Stop the application, run `npm cache clear` then re-run the application.

Either way the example above is working my end.

Comment: i'm already running in a wildfly server, still the color doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

turns out that we had in the custom css file this line: `.input { background:#0f0f0f !important;}`
i just deleted the `!important` and everything worked as expected.